# passing list to sql in python

Tags: python, sql, list

I am trying to pass a list to sql. From what I found, there is no `bind`type for a list. So, I tried converting the list to a string : 
Here is the sql I am trying to execute :

```
select a,b,sum(c) as total from t where d in ('x','y') group by 1,2
```

AS I had to parametrize it , I used the below:

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc
#conn_vertica -- connection object to vertica
f_list = ['x','y']
sql_test=   select a,b,sum(c) as total from t where d in (%s) group by 1,2
l = ', '.join(map(lambda x: '%s',f_list))
sql_test = sql_test % l
df_test = pd.read_sql(sql_test,conn_vertica) # to read it into a dataframe
```

On running this I get an error :

```
pandas.io.sql.DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'select a, b, sum(c) as total from t where d in (%s, %s)  group by 1,2': ('42601', '[42601] ERROR 4856:  Syntax error at or near "%" at character 123\n (4856) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

Any suggestions on how to pass a list into sql

Comment: On printing sql_test after the line sql_test = sql_test % l , this is the output : **select  a,b,sum(c) as total from t where d in (%s, %s) group by 1,2**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass it as a tuple:

```
sql_test = "SELECT a, b, SUM(c) AS total FROM t WHERE d IN {0} GROUP BY 1, 2".format(tuple(f_list))

>>> sql_test
"SELECT a, b, SUM(c) AS total FROM t WHERE d IN ('x', 'y') GROUP BY 1, 2"
```

Comment: Thanks @Alexander, it worked. Are there any other ways to do this?  Was my approach wrong?

Comment: There are generally several ways to accomplish the same task, although "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it." I am not familiar enough with pyodbc to comment on your method.

Comment: :okay.  In my query, I need to pass multiple parameters. So, for the first parameter I used {0} and .format(tupe(list)) . For the second parameter I tried using {1} ( this number indicates the position of the parameter) : Query looks like this : **sql_test = "SELECT a, b, SUM(c) AS total FROM t WHERE d IN {0} and e = to_date({1},'YYYY-mm-dd') GROUP BY 1, 2".format(tuple(f_list),historical_date)**         historical_date = '2015-05-01' -- this was initialized at the beginning. I am getting an error that , there is no method to_date(int,unknown)   is this usage wrong

Comment: `...and e = {1}...format(tuple(f_list), historical_date)` might work. If not, it is a pyodbc issue.

Comment: I tried that...when I printed the sql ..this is how it looked . e = 2015-05-01 .........and error : was **explict type cast might be required** ...I tried using str(historical_start_date) but it still printed without quotes..is there a way to print it as a string or may be append quotes to it ...i.e e = '2015-05-01'

Comment: thnks, it worked. I used where e = to_date('{1}','YYYY-MM-DD') ...and at the end I passed the variable historical_start_date

Comment: This does not work when a single item is given for the formatting. A tuple with a single element is represented as:

tuple([1]) = '(1,)'

This breaks the sql